# EF Core - Filtro para Particionamento

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Estou trabalhando em um banco que possui a seguinte característica, 90% um índice clusterizado que integra duas colunas.: `FilialID` e `DataCriacao`.

Estas tabelas são particionadas pelo `FilialID`, a simples criação ou remoção de uma `Filial` provoca a recriação destas partições.

A nível de sistema, `FilialID` é único e pode ser obtido de forma global, então preciso adicionar um `filtro` padrão em todas as consultas, onde todas as entidades que possuam a propriedade `FilialID` serão filtradas por ele.

por exemplo, se eu fizer a seguinte consulta.:

```
var entity = db.EntitiesA
    .Include(x => x.EntitiesB)
    .Include(x => c.EntitiesC)
    .Find(x => x.EntityAID = id);
```

deverá gerar uma consulta semelhante a seguinte.:

```
SELECT *
FROM EntitiesA A
JOIN EntitiesB B ON A.EntityAID = B.EntityAID
JOIN EntitiesB C ON A.EntityAID = C.EntityAID
WHERE 
    A.EntityAID = @id AND
    A.FilialID = @filialId AND
    B.FilialID = @filialId AND
    C.FilialID = @filialId
```

**MOTIVAÇÂO**

> Queries
>
> Queries that use partition elimination could have comparable or
>   improved performance with larger number of partitions. Queries that do
>   not use partition elimination could take longer to execute as the
>   number of partitions increases.
>
> For example, assume a table has 100 million rows and columns A, B, and
>   C. In scenario 1, the table is divided into 1000 partitions on column
>   A. In scenario 2, the table is divided into 10,000 partitions on
>   column A. **A query on the table that has a WHERE clause filtering on
>   column A will perform partition elimination and scan one partition.**
>   That same query may run faster in scenario 2 as there are fewer rows
>   to scan in a partition. **A query that has a WHERE clause filtering on
>   column B will scan all partitions.** The query may run faster in
>   scenario 1 than in scenario 2 as there are fewer partitions to scan.
>
> Queries that use operators such as TOP or MAX/MIN on columns other
>   than the partitioning column may experience reduced performance with
>   partitioning because all partitions must be evaluated.

O resultado da consulta acima será o mesmo, caso eu informe o `FilialID` ou omita o mesmo, porém ao informar o mesmo, as partições referentes as demais `Filiais` serão ignoradas, assim evitando `locks` desnecessários e melhorando o desempenho da consulta.

**EDIT**

Tentativa utilizando o `Query Filter` do `EntityFramework-Plus`, mas o mesmo não funciona com Includes.

```
public MyContext()
{
    this.Filter<EntityA>(set => set.Where(entity => entity.FilialID == Global.FilialID));
    this.Filter<EntityB>(set => set.Where(entity => entity.FilialID == Global.FilialID));
    this.Filter<EntityC>(set => set.Where(entity => entity.FilialID == Global.FilialID));
}
```

Comment: Note que essa vantagem da partição só é verdade para a primeira tabela na query. No seu primeiro exemplo, só é vantajoso ter a `FilialID` na tabela pai, ou seja, `EntitiesA`. Como a `EntitiesB` e `EntitiesC` já estão "amarradas" na `EntitiesA` provavelmente por uma foreign key, adicionar o campo `FilialID` nessas duas além de ser redundante, não ajuda em nada no desempenho (aliás, pode causar uma verificação a mais que é desnecessária). Mas para a primeira de fato é interessante sim, ou se você tiver que fazer `JOIN` com uma tabela que não tem FK com as demais, aí também faria sentido.

Comment: Agora voltando a pergunta, sua intenção é adicionar automaticamente um `WHERE()` na query (talvez dentro do `DbContext`) para filtrar esse campo `FiltroID` (desde que `Global.FilialID` tenha algum valor preenchido), sem precisar esquentar a cabeça com isso no resto do sistema, é isso?

Comment: Btw minha primeira afirmação não é válida se você pode ter o mesmo Id de EntityA para diferentes filiais, ou seja, se a tabela for chave dupla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na data desta resposta:

- Existe uma biblioteca que te permite usar filtros dinâmicos, a [EntityFramework.DynamicFilters](https://github.com/jcachat/EntityFramework.DynamicFilters), mas [ela não possui suporte ao EF Core porque a cadeia de eventos para ela ser viável ainda não está pronta](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/626);
- [Há um projeto que adiciona alguns eventos](https://github.com/Antaris/EntityFrameworkCoreExtensions), mas ele ainda é bastante cru;
- [`.Include()` com filtro está no *roadmap*, mas não está pronto](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/1833).

Duas alternativas:

- Voltar para o Entity Framework 6;
- Usar uma forma dolorosa.

A forma dolorosa é:

```
var entity = db.EntitiesA
    .Include(x => x.EntitiesB)
    .Include(x => c.EntitiesC)
    .Where(...)
    .FiltrarPorFilial();
```

`.FiltrarPorFilial()` é uma extensão:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FiltrarPorFilial(this IQueryable<T> consulta)
{
    foreach (var registro in consulta.ToList()) 
    {
        // Faça aqui yield return de todos os registros que estejam nas condições desejadas. 
    }
}
```

Comment: Vi aqui o Roadmap do EF Core 2.0: `Global query filters (`[`#5774`](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/5774)`) - Allows a vertical filter to be configured for an entity type. This filter then applies to all queries, including eager loading (i.e. Include()).`

Comment: So lembrando que filtro global é uma coisa, e filtro por demanda no `Include()` é outra. O filtro global funciona para `Includes()`, mas ele não tem o mesmo poder de expressão do filtro dinâmico, como no EntityFramework.DynamicFilters.

Answer (score 3):

A resposta do cigano me levou até o `EF Core 2.0`, assim como o [`Roadmap`](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Roadmap#ef-core-20-under-development) e o [`Preview`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/05/12/announcing-ef-core-2-0-preview-1/) do mesmo.

No EF 2.0 é possível fazer o seguinte:

```
public abstract class EntidadeBase
{
    public Guid FilialID { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataCriacao { get; set; }
}

public class EntidadeA : EntidadeBase
{
    public Guid EntidadeAID { get; set; }

    public ICollection<EntidadeB> EntidadesB { get; set; }
    public ICollection<EntidadeC> EntidadesC { get; set; }
}

public class EntidadeB : EntidadeBase
{
    public Guid EntidadeBID { get; set; }
    public Guid EntidadeAID { get; set; }
    public EntidadeA EntidadeA { get; set; }
}

public class EntidadeC : EntidadeBase
{
    public Guid EntidadeCID { get; set; }
    public Guid EntidadeAID { get; set; }
    public EntidadeA EntidadeA { get; set; }
}

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public static Guid FilialID { get; set; }

    public DbSet<EntidadeA> EntidadesA { get; set; }
    public DbSet<EntidadeB> EntidadesB { get; set; }
    public DbSet<EntidadeC> EntidadesB { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<EntidadeBase>().HasQueryFilter(p => p.FilialID == MyContext.FilialID);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Não sei se entendi muito bem a sua pergunta, mais ao que parece você quer gerar uma consulta genérica com um filtro global, visto que na sua aplicação o campo `FilialId` é um campo global.

Uma abordagem que pode atender à sua necessidade seria a criação de um `IQueryable` da tabela desejada dentro do contexto, que já implementaria o seu filtro, abaixo um exemplo:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<EntityA> EntitiesASet { get; set; }

    public IQueryable<EntityA> EntitiesA
    {
        return EntitiesASet
                   .Include(x => x.EntitiesB)
                   .Include(x => c.EntitiesC)
                   .Where(x => x.FilialID == Global.FilialID);
    }
}
```

Neste caso, quando você chamar o código:

```
var dados = db.EntitiesA.ToList();
```

Os dados já irão vir filtrados com o filtro desejado.

***Observação:*** *Eu já usei abordagens como esta no EntityFramework 6.1.3, nunca testei com o EF Core, mais acredito que vá funcionar.*

Comment: FilialID não é a chave primária, então x.EntityAID == Global.FilialID não deve trazer nada, a menos que haja uma colisão de guids (muito improvável).

Comment: O FilialID não deve interferir no resultado das consultas, mas para fazer bom uso das funções de particionamento, preciso incluir todos os campos cluesterizados das tabelas particionadas envolvidas na consulta no Where.

Comment: Então independente de utilizar include ou joins, faça o lazy ou o eager load, a condição deve ser adicionada.

Comment: @TobiasMesquita, então o que vc precisa é agrupar por filialID?

Comment: Você não tem uma foreign Key que interliga EntityA, EntityB e EntityC por meio do campo "FilialID" ?